# AngularFire Storage get file url

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage, angularfire, angularfire2

I have a problem with getDownloadURL() method from AngularFire Storage. I couldn't use then() without an error.

Here is my code :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

import { AngularFireModule } from 'angularfire2';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { AngularFireStorage } from 'angularfire2/storage';

import { GroupDetailsPage } from '../group-details/group-details';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private afDB: AngularFireDatabase, private afStorage: AngularFireStorage) {


        let ref = this.afStorage.ref('test.jpg');
            ref.getDownloadURL().then(function(url){
                console.log( url );
            });

    }

}
```

Here my error :
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: ref.getDownloadURL(...).then is not a function

If I don't use then() I get a PromiseObservable as response.

Have you got an idea ?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just get the file url using

```
let ref = this.afStorage.ref('test.jpg');
this.url = ref.getDownloadURL();
```

And use it with the **async** pipe in your template file.

Comment: What to do if I need to save/download the file using this URL?